# The Mysterious "usage" Tag in Visual Studio Documentation XML Comment Tags

Tags: .net, visual-studio, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, xml-documentation

I often use XML documentation to document my classes, methods and properties but take a look at this method from Microsoft:

[image]

**Usage**? What kind of sorcery is this? How does one emulate this wizardry?

There's no such thing in the source code, I checked (.Net 4.5). There's no xmldoc tag for it either, it isn't supposed to exist and yet it shows up in the tooltip.

I noticed it a while back but haven't had time to investigate so now I had and I wasted at least an hour trying to figure it out in vain.

It's a nice thing because it shows up in tooltips. We do have the `<example>` tag but that's not it, this is a different beast entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I can find is the [`<code>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/code) element, but it doesn't provide such neat output as one at the image.

It looks like it's hardcoded to `Task` static methods somewhere inside the Visual Studio: [reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,298c51c20d5a4fad) and [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5634) do not contain such xml comments, and I didn't find any other methods with such `Usage` thing, even the `async` ones.

Maybe it's a part of Visual Studio support for `async/await` syntax, notifying the developer to not forget to await the created task.

**Update**: I think that this is a Visual Studio behavior. Consider such code:

```
public static Task<int> TestMethod1()
{
    return Task.FromResult(9);
}

public static async Task<int> TestMethod2()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(9);
}
```

[image: Usage for TestMethod1]

[image: Usage for TestMethod2]

Both of such methods will get the `Usage` section in pop-up, without any xml comments. So this is a reminder for developer to not forget to await the `Task`s.