# Add usage information for a function in its Visual Studio tooltip

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add information on how to use my function in the Visual Studio tooltip, similar to how it is done by default with every [`async` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0GL7.png).

Example:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Executes an asynchron operation
/// </summary>
/// <usage> <-- I am looking for something like this
/// try
/// {
///     bool x = await DoSomething();
/// }
/// finally
/// {
///    await CleanUp();
/// }
/// </usage>
public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    return await SomeAsynchronOperation();
}
```

I tried using the `<example>` tag, but this text is not shown in the tooltip.

There is no description of any other tag in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) that allows something like that.

How is it done with the `async` functions and is there a possibility to do the same thing for other functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to me like a special VisualStudio feature for `Task`  based methods only.

The `Task` [reference code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/f82e13c3820cd04553c21bf6da01262b95d9bd43/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5677-L5689) doesn't show anything special in XML comment related to the way you should call it:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a proxy for the
        /// Task returned by <paramref name="function"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="function">The work to execute asynchronously</param>
        /// <returns>A Task that represents a proxy for the Task returned by <paramref name="function"/>.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// The <paramref name="function"/> parameter was null.
        /// </exception>
        public static Task Run(Func<Task> function)
        {
            return Run(function, default(CancellationToken));
        }
```

I guess the only thing you can do is to use a combination of `<example>` and `<code>` tags.

```
 ///<summary>Credit account with amount passed as parameter</summary>
 ///<example>After class initialisation, call this method:
 ///<code>
 ///var account = new Account(10, 2000);
 ///account.Credit(5000);
 ///</code>
 ///</example>
 public void Credit(int amount)
 {
   Balance = amount + Balance;
 }
```

VS Code will respect that and would render something like
[image]
(Example taken from [this site](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-code-example-tags-csharp-xml-documentation-comments))

**UPD**
Apparently, there is a [similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708558/the-mysterious-usage-tag-in-visual-studio-documentation-xml-comment-tags)

Comment: I think you're right. I'm now using an `<example>` tag inside the `<summary>` tag. This way there is at least some information in the VisualStudio tooltip, even though the formatting is not that nice.